NuGet: Unable to load the service index for source
I use VS 2022. I need to use a specific source for nuget packages of my company. I have done all the steps described in this video (go straight to 1:45 - from this moment I start my work as a developer, I don`t push my own packages to the server): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQ_GzpgLhlY The only thing I've changed is the source link. I also use OpenVPN to access the server.
After adding a new source, I tried to get the available packages in the NuGet Package Manager, but I had a problem:

[baget] Unable to load the service index for source https://proget.garvex.tech/nuget/garveks/v3/index.json
An error occurred while sending the request.
The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
This method is not supported by this class.

I've tried all the steps from the answer to a similar question here: Nuget "This method is not supported by this class"
But it didn't work out for me.

Well, I just used "nuget install [nuget_name] -version [nuget_version] -source [source_name]". There were some dependency issues (for example, "Unable to resolve dependency 'System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler'"), but they are solved by simply installing these missing packages from nuget.org . That's all.

Test accessing the NuGet source via the command line to isolate whether the issue is with Visual Studio or the NuGet server itself. Open a command prompt and run:
nuget list -Source https://proget.garvex.tech/nuget/garveks/v3/index.json -Verbosity detailed

Make sure your credentials are correctly configured in Visual Studio.

It didn't really help me with my problem, but I've already solved it with "nuget install". But anyway, thanks for answering!
